# VueJs/Vuetify/VueDraggable - How to make VListGroup items draggable?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vuedraggable

Using Vuetify and VueDraggable, I'm trying to make the items under the VListGroup draggable.

About code, what I want to do is going from [here](https://codepen.io/lowdown/pen/vYEQpqj) to [there](https://codepen.io/lowdown/pen/povQpwB) (atm list items in groups are not draggable in this codepen).

### Without VListGroups:

#### Template

```
<draggable v-model="controls"
           :group="draggable.group"
           :sort="false"
           tag="v-list"
           :component-data="draggable.componentData">
    <v-list-item v-for="(control, index) in controls"
                 :key="index"
                 link>
      <v-list-item-title v-text="control.name"></v-list-item-title>
      <v-list-item-icon>
        <v-icon v-text="control.icon"></v-icon>
      </v-list-item-icon>
    </v-list-item>
</draggable>
```

#### Data

```
data: () => ({
  draggable: {
    group: {
      name: 'formbuilder',
      pull: 'clone',
      put: 'false',
    },
    componentData: {
      props: {
        dense: true,
      },
    },
  },
  controls: [
    { name: 'Row', icon: 'mdi-table-row' },
    { name: 'Column', icon: 'mdi-table-column' },
    { name: 'Text', icon: 'mdi-text-short' },
    { name: 'Text area', icon: 'mdi-text-subject' },
    { name: 'Select', icon: 'mdi-filter-variant' },
    { name: 'Checkbox & switch', icon: 'mdi-checkbox-marked' },
    { name: 'Radio group', icon: 'mdi-radiobox-marked' },
  ],
}),
```

### With VListGroup

#### Template

```
<v-list dense
        expand>
  <v-list-group v-for="(group, index) in controlsGroups"
                :prepend-icon="group.icon"
                no-action>
    <template v-slot:activator>
      <v-list-item-title v-text="group.name"></v-list-item-title>
    </template>
    <v-list-item v-for="(control, index) in group.controls"
                 :key="index"
                 link>
      <v-list-item-title v-text="control.name"></v-list-item-title>
      <v-list-item-icon>
        <v-icon v-text="control.icon"></v-icon>
      </v-list-item-icon>
  </v-list-group>
</v-list>
```

#### Data

```
data: () => ({
  controlsGroups: [
    {
      name: 'Layouts',
      icon: 'mdi-view-dashboard',
      controls: [
        { name: 'Row', icon: 'mdi-table-row' },
        { name: 'Column', icon: 'mdi-table-column' }
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'inputs',
      icon: 'mdi-textbox',
      controls: [
        { name: 'Text', icon: 'mdi-text-short' },
        { name: 'Text area', icon: 'mdi-text-subject' },
        { name: 'Select', icon: 'mdi-filter-variant' },
        { name: 'Checkbox & switch', icon: 'mdi-checkbox-marked' },
        { name: 'Radio group', icon: 'mdi-radiobox-marked' },
      ],
    },
  ],
}),
```

My problem is that it seems that I can't use the activator slot of the VListGroup with the component-data prop of VueDraggable...

Any idea on how I can achieve that ?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. Is this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rqknjs08/embedded works for you?